# update multiple rows by one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to update multiple rows by one mysql update query.this is my code.but it didn't work.it display error.i'm trying to update start and end field in mysql table

```
$resname=$_POST['resname'];
$rw1start=$_POST['rw1start'];
$rw1end=$_POST['rw1end'];
$rw2start=$_POST['rw2start'];
$rw2end=$_POST['rw2end'];
$rw3start=$_POST['rw3start'];
$rw3end=$_POST['rw3end'];
$rw4start=$_POST['rw4start'];
$rw4end=$_POST['rw4end'];
$rw5start=$_POST['rw5start'];
$rw5end=$_POST['rw5end'];
$rw6start=$_POST['rw6start'];
$rw6end=$_POST['rw6end'];
$rw7start=$_POST['rw7start'];
$rw7end=$_POST['rw7end'];

    $sql="UPDATE opening 
            SET start = (case when day = 'Monday' then '$rw1start'
                             when day = 'Tuesday' then '$rw2start'
                             when day = 'Wednesday' then '$rw3start'
                              when day = 'Thursday' then '$rw4start'
                               when day = 'Friday' then '$rw5start'
                                when day = 'Saturday' then '$rw6start'
                                 when day = 'Sunday' then '$rw7start'
                        end),
            SET end = (case when day = 'Monday' then '$rw1end'
                             when day = 'Tuesday' then '$rw2end'
                             when day = 'Wednesday' then '$rw3end'
                              when day = 'Thursday' then '$rw4end'
                               when day = 'Friday' then '$rw5end'
                                when day = 'Saturday' then '$rw6end'
                                 when day = 'Sunday' then '$rw7end'
                        end)        


                    WHERE (day in 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday') AND res_name='$resname'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql)or die ("Error");
```

[image: opening table]

Comment: You are passing POST values directly to your query. That is dangerous practice, you should escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Your update command is not correct in addition you have column name `end` which is reserved. You need to backtick it. You have used `set` 2 times but in update statement you need only once as

```
update table set col1 = 'someval',col2='someval' 


$sql="UPDATE opening 
SET start = (
               case 
               when day = 'Monday' then '$rw1start'
               when day = 'Tuesday' then '$rw2start'
               when day = 'Wednesday' then '$rw3start'
               when day = 'Thursday' then '$rw4start'
               when day = 'Friday' then '$rw5start'
               when day = 'Saturday' then '$rw6start'
               when day = 'Sunday' then '$rw7start'
               end
             ),
     `end` = (
               case 
               when day = 'Monday' then '$rw1end'
               when day = 'Tuesday' then '$rw2end'
               when day = 'Wednesday' then '$rw3end'
               when day = 'Thursday' then '$rw4end'
               when day = 'Friday' then '$rw5end'
               when day = 'Saturday' then '$rw6end'
               when day = 'Sunday' then '$rw7end'
               end
             ) 
           WHERE day in ('Monday', 'Tuesday',  'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday') 
           AND res_name='$resname'";
```

Comment: no any other error message.i use error reporting "ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);".only display "Error" from $result=mysql_query($sql)or die ("Error");

Comment: use `$result=mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());` and see what is the actual error.

Comment: It' display -  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday') AND re' at line 26

Comment: oh  i missed the where section that you have. Let me update my answer.